# I am not able to create table from SQL Workbench in Redshift whereas I am able to create table using Python from Jupyter

Tags: python, mysql, sql, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am new to this forum but I am a avid user for this forum.

I want to create a table in particular schema in Redshift but not able to do so from SQL Workbench, but at the same time if I sending the same query from Python the same table is getting updated.

Can anybody help me on this?

The SQL code is given below : -

CREATE TABLE schema name.table name 
(
  a   FLOAT(53),
  b   FLOAT(53)
);

The Python code is given below : -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5),columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
print(df)

ONN_STR = "postgresql+psycopg2://redshift URL" 
red_engine =create_engine(CONN_STR)


df.to_redshift(table_name="table_name", schema ='schema_name',                   #engine=red_engine,s3_bucket="",s3_keypath="",                 if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong in SQL Workbench?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what happens when you run the create statement in SQL Workbench, e.g. is there an error message?

Comment: Yes whenever I am trying to create a table through SQL Workbench I am getting - ERROR: permission denied for schema rsds_gpa
1 statement failed. But the same operation is getting execute through my Python code.

Comment: That seems a pretty clear error to me - it sounds like you are not connecting with the same user in SQL Workbench as you are in Python, and the SQL Workbench user does not have sufficient permissions to create a table in the specified schema.

Comment: @Nathan I am accessing the SQL Workbench through the same login credentials but its still not allowing me to do the same

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code in the last statement:

```
df.to_sql("table_name", connectionname, index=False ,if_exists="replace")
```

Comment: The question is about why the query *in SQL Workbench* does not work. The python code is apparently working OK as it is.

Comment: SQL Workbench /J.. connection have schema (database) associate with it. so we cant see other schema tables apart from default.